# How to Add Button Image for Calender in MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, master-pages

I have a page for employee which does insertion.There is a field called as datehired.It requires a calender.I don't know to insert a calender image for the button.I can add a image by writing this code

Likewise how to add an icon for button for calender
I am using Visual Studio 2010 framework 4.0

```html
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="BACKIMAGE.jpg" />
```

Comment: I am using a aspx calender (for a button).Please help me with this.@SuprabhatBiswal

Comment: So, whats is the actual problem here.Are you not able to open a calendar in image button click or You want a themed button in which you want to place an image layer over the button?

Comment: Yes I wanna place an image layer over the button.what's the code should I type for that? @SuprabhatBiswal

Comment: In asp you can find a control named ImageButton try using it. It consist of both image and button property.